# How do I solve this error of Pymongo? cursor id not found pymongo

Tags: python, django, mongodb, ubuntu, pymongo

I'm getting the whole data of some collection in MongoDB and after a while (like 30 or 60 minutes), the script raises the following error:

> pymongo.errors.CursorNotFound: cursor id 1801580172063793986 not found, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'cursor id 1801580172063793986 not found', 'code': 43, 'codeName': 'CursorNotFound'}

This error occurs after the 24k documents. I'm using Django and Pymongo connected to the database on the local server. The collection has like 60k documents.

This is how I'm getting the data:

```py
client = MongoClient(settings.MONGO_HOST, settings.MONGO_PORT)
collection = client[settings.MONGO_DB].collection
cursor = collection.find(no_cursor_timeout=True)
for document in cursor:
    # getting the data from the user
```

Just in case, I'm using:

- Python  3.8
- Django  3.1.4
- Pymongo 3.11.0
- Mongod  4.4.2 (for the local server)
- Ubuntu  20.04

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not the solution to the error, but this is a way to avoid the error.
In order to use the cursor in the minimum time possible, you can save all the data in a list or something like that.

```py
client = MongoClient(settings.MONGO_HOST, settings.MONGO_PORT)
collection = client[settings.MONGO_DB].collection
cursor = collection.find(no_cursor_timeout=True)

collection_data = [document for document in cursor]
for document in collection_data:
    # using the data
```

Answer (score 2):

See https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-36808 and the related linked tickets.

The server can destroy sessions that are being used by open cursors, which has the effect of rendering those cursors unusable.

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-1626 might be helpful though it seems to me the issue is on the server side and as of now unresolved.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the cursor timeout globally via `cursorTimeoutMillis` parameter.

In your terminal, type:

```sh
$ mongod --setParameter cursorTimeoutMillis=600000
```

Comment: I have tried that, but I still get that error